# factory girl does not load a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, relation

I'm using factory girl to test a rails app.

A user belongs_to Adresse.

I want to test a user with an adresse, here is my user factory :

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    nom_proprietaire    { Faker::Name.first_name }
    email    { Faker::Internet.email}
    raison_sociale    { Faker::Company.name}
    password               "password"
    password_confirmation  "password"
    adresse
  end

  factory :user_with_recurring_order_to_generate, parent: :user do
    after(:build) {|u| FactoryGirl.create(:contrat_with_active_product, :user=>u)}
  end
end
```

Here is my adresse factory :

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :adresse do
    nom_prenom   "qfsd"
    #{ Faker::Name.first_name }
    adresse_ligne_1    { Faker::Address.street_address}
    ville { Faker::Address.city}
    code_postal { Faker::Address.zip_code}
    pays { Faker::Address.country}
    telephone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number}
  end
end
```

However when i use user in a test i have the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   La validation a échoué : Ville doit être rempli(e)
```

Meaning that i do not respect validate presence of ville for my adresse. How can i tell to factory girl to use my adresse factory when i want to create an adresse ?

EDIT : My code is fine, it's the faker gem who is broken for french...

Answer (score 0):

My code is fine, it's the Faker gem that is broken for french.